# Finite difference applied to a product

Tags: calculus, derivatives, finite-differences

I believe that the finite difference

$$\frac{f(x_0 + \frac12 \Delta x) - f(x_0 - \frac12 \Delta x)}{\Delta x}$$

approximates $f'$, and has limit $f'(x_0)$ as $\Delta x \to 0$. Am I correct in reasoning from this that given two functions $\alpha (x)$, $\beta(x)$ differentiable at $x_0$, we have that

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\alpha(x_0 - \Delta x)\beta(x_0 - \Delta x) - \alpha(x_0 + \Delta x)\beta(x_0 + \Delta x)}{\Delta x}\\ = -2(\alpha \beta)'(x_0) = -2\alpha'(x_0)\beta(x_0) - 2\alpha(x_0) \beta'(x_0)?$$

Thanks

Comment: This is called the [product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) but your reasoning is incomplete.  Can you show more of your steps?

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the product rule, just shaky in applying it to finite differences. I'll describe them briefly...swap plus and minus gives minus, multiply by 2 to get $2\Delta x$ in the denominator for the centered finite difference

Comment: I don't see how you are using finite differences here except in the sense of the definition of the derivative.

Comment: Well, this isn't quite the definition of the derivative that I learned since it is not the forward difference...I'm trying to learn how to get the derivative from the centered difference, you could say. Also making sure I am correct in my manipulations

Comment: I think the first equality follows directly from your assumption (just set $f(x) = \alpha(x) \cdot \beta(x)$) and the second is simply the product rule.  Although admittedly I don't know in exactly what cases your assumption is true.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{2}\delta) - f(x-\frac{1}{2}\delta)}{\delta} = \frac{f(x+\frac{1}{2}\delta) - f(x)+f(x)-f(x-\frac{1}{2}\delta)}{\delta} =\frac{1}{2} \frac{f(x+\frac{1}{2}\delta) - f(x)}{\frac{1}{2}\delta} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{f(x-\frac{1}{2}\delta) -f(x)}{-\frac{1}{2}\delta}$.

It follows that $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{f(x+\frac{1}{2}\delta) - f(x-\frac{1}{2}\delta)}{\delta} = f'(x)$.

The formula for the product $\alpha \beta$ follows from the product rule $(\alpha \beta)' = \alpha' \beta + \alpha \beta'$ (and scaling by $2$ in the formulation above).

Comment: Wait but if $f(x) = \sin(x)$ for $x \ge 0$ and $f(x) = \cos(x) - 1$ for $x \lt 0$ then $f'(0) = 1$ but the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$, right?

Comment: @DanBrumleve: No, that function would not be differentiable at $x=0$. (The limit of the finite differences would be $\frac{1}{2}$, as you wrote.)

Comment: Err right I'm confusing the forward difference with a directional limit.  The limit has to be the same from both sides for the derivative to be defined.